# Remember last branch in git Pull in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I do VCS>Git>pull I get the dialogue with all the branches but I always need to recheck the branch I want to pull. Is there a way of remembering the last branch in git Pull, maybe this should be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Now it's not possible

But you can easily navigate to particular branch using **[Speed Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html)** just start to typing name of branch

This feature is awesome try to use it in almost every popup or dialog window for navigation to item by name